# How to get Request object in Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

I need to check a lot of items from my db with Guzzle. For example, amount of items is 2000-5000. It is too many to load it all in a single array, so I want to break it in chunks: SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 100. When last item is sent to Guzzle then next 100 items are requested. In 'fulfilled' handler I should know which item got the response. I see that we have $index here, which points to the number of current item. But I don't have an access to scope where $items variable is visible. Anyway, if I even get access it via use($items) then in second pass of the loop I get wrong index, because indexes in $items array will start from 0, while $index will be >100. So, this method will not work.

```
    $client = new Client();
    $iterator = function() {
         while($items = getSomeItemsFromDb(100)) {
              foreach($items as $item) {
                   echo "Start item #{$item['id']}";
                   yield new Request('GET', $item['url']);
              }
         }
    };

    $pool = new Pool($client, $iterator(), [
        'concurrency' => 20,
        'fulfilled' => function (ResponseInterface $response, $index) {
            // how to get $item['id'] here?
        },
        'rejected' => function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
            call_user_func($this->error_handler, $reason, $index);
        }
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();
```

I think if I could do something like

```
$request = new Request('GET', $item['url']);
$request->item = $item;
```

and then in 'fulfilled' handler just to get $request from $response - that would be ideal. But as I can see, there is no way to do something like $response->getRequest(). 
Any suggestions about how to solve this?

Comment: You could yield back an array `yield [ 'request' => new Request('GET', $item['url']), 'id' => $item['id'] ];`

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's not possible in Guzzle to get the request. See response  creation for more details.

But you can just return a different promise and use `each_limit()` instead of `Pool` (internally the pool class is just a wrapper around `EachPromise`). It's more general solution and works with any types of promises.

Also take a look at [another example of EachPromise usage for concurrent HTTP request](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/concurrent-http-requests/).

```
$client = new Client();
$iterator = function () use ($client) {
    while ($items = getSomeItemsFromDb(100)) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo "Start item #{$item['id']}";
            yield $client
                ->sendAsync(new Request('GET', $item['url']))
                ->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($item) {
                    return [$item['id'], $response];
                });
        }
    }
};

$promise = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit(
    $iterator(),
    20,
    function ($result, $index) {
        list($itemId, $response) = $result;

        // ...
    },
    function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
        call_user_func($this->error_handler, $reason, $index);
    }
);

$promise->wait();
```